# terraform replace variable inside json

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

i am creating rds server using terraform. I pass options group using list variable. The options groups variable in variable.tf like below

```
options = [
   {
    option_name = "SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE"

    option_settings=[
      {
      name  = "IAM_ROLE_ARN"
      value = "${role_arn}"
    },
  ]
},
```

i want replace the "${role_arn}" variable in main.tf . Can any one help with syntax ?

Answer (score 13):

I solve this kind of issue using [terraform template files](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file).

1. Move your json to a separate file;
2. update yout json to use [Terraform template syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html?&_ga=2.132520782.1172820809.1596803130-1862772819.1594630096#string-templates);
3. add a data resource to render and parse your template;
4. reference your rendered template in your resource.

Let's say that you'll need something like:

```
resource "provider_resource" "name" {
  property = "value"
  options = [
    {
      option_name = "SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE"
      option_settings = [
        {
          name  = "IAM_ROLE_ARN"
          value = "${role_arn}"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

after the change you will have something like:

```
data "template_file" "json_template" {
  template = file("path/to/file.json")
  vars = {
    role_arn = var.dynamic_value
  }
}

resource "provider_resource" "name" {
  property = "value"
  options = data.template_file.json_template.rendered
}
```

Comment: Cheers .this is helping @gustavo... i passed this to resource options group code from https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-rds/tree/master/modules/db_option_group              .... It throws error Cannot use a string value in for_each. An iterable collection is required....... any variable conversion ??

Comment: in your case the options is a list. If you will have only one value inside this list, you can change the options value to be an list with the rendered template as its single value. ex: remove the array from your json and change the resource to use `options = [data.template_file.json_template.rendered]`. If you'll need more than one value then you'll need to make more research.

Comment: Appreciate your reposne @gustavo will try this... i was trying function tolist(data.template_file.json_template.rendered) to covert to list . doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Building on the template_file approach, the [`templatefile`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) function allows to do this with minimal verbosity:

```
resource "provider_resource" "name" {
  property = "value"
  options  = templatefile("path/to/file.json", { role_arn = var.dynamic_value })
}
```